# Gmaps4rails : Clustering not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

Since [Gmaps4rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) updated to 1.5 the clustering option has been set to false by default.
The [documentation](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Markers) says that :do_clustering its the way to show clusters on flooding markers.

In code i´ve got:

```
    <%= gmaps(:markers => {:data => @json}, :map_options => {:do_clustering => true}) %>
```

Edit: And of course [it is supported](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvG8BjhQ7xttdEFKR0JwT1BkbGxFbVQtcFExUGQtbGc&hl=fr#gid=0)

But clusters still not showing. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you rerun the rake task to get the fresh assets into your app?

Comment: Do you mean rails generate gmaps4rails:install ? This displays all my .js.coffee to identical, and prompts to replace my css (which i deny because of my styles).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just realized:

You're passing `do_clustering` as a map option whereas it's a marker option.

Comment: For the record, the correct code is: gmaps(:markers => {:data => @json, :options => { :do_clustering => true} })

Comment: Nice :) I didn't write it since it's hell to write code on iphone!